# Primary Colors of Light Other that RGB

Tags: color

I came across this paragraph in [this](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-2/Color-Addition) website:

> Any three colors (or frequencies) of light that produce white light
>   when combined with the correct intensity are called primary colors of
>   light. There are a variety of sets of primary colors. The most common
>   set of primary colors is red (R), green (G) and blue (B).

It says, there are a variety sets of primary colors. Can you name other primary colors of light other than RGB based on the above definition?

Based on this definition C, M and Y in CMY color model or R, Y and B in RYB color model are not primary colors. This is in contrast to the defintion in [Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_color).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with photography.

Comment: Can you please point me to the right stack exchange forum?

Comment: @PhilipKendall if the question was a bit edited to be about CMYK, RGB and if there are other systems - or why RGB is chosen - then I'd think it would make perfect sense here.

Comment: [This website](http://www.strollswithmydog.com) has good articles on the subject.

Comment: Maybe https://physics.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 4):

### Light spectrum vs. color sets

[Your citation](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-2/Color-Addition) misses the most important parts of the paragraph. In my opinion, this is the important part:

> [...] When we speak of white light, we are referring to ROYGBIV [[Link to Wikipedia's article on ROYGBIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROYGBIV)] - the presence of the entire spectrum of visible light. But **combining the range of frequencies in the visible light spectrum is not the only means of producing white light. White light can also be produced by combining only three distinct frequencies of light, provided that they are widely separated on the visible light spectrum**. Any three colors (or frequencies) of light that produce white light when combined with the correct intensity are called primary colors of light. [...]

[As Wikipedia states in its simple article about primary colors](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_color):

> **Primary colors** [...] are **sets of colors** that can be **combined to make a useful range of colors**. The **primary colors are those which cannot be created by mixing other colors in a given color space**.

> For **subtractive combination of colors**, as in mixing of pigments or dyes for printing, the primaries normally used are **cyan, magenta, and yellow**, though the set of red, yellow, blue is popular among artists.

> For **additive combination of colors**, as in overlapping projected lights or in CRT displays, the primary colors normally used are **red, green, and blue**.

In your case, we are talking about additive color models.

---

### Additive and subtractive color models

**Additive, as in "all primary colors together are white by adding them"**. Red cannot be mixed by adding blue to green, blue cannot be mixed by adding green to red, and green cannot be mixed by adding blue to red:

[image: additive color mixing by Wikipedia]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/AdditiveColorMixiing.svg/504px-AdditiveColorMixiing.svg.png))</sub>

<sub>Stolen from [Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_color)</sub>

**Subtractive, as in "all primary colors together are black by subtracting them"**. Cyan cannot be mixed by subtracting magenta from yellow, yellow cannot be mixed by subtracting magenta from cyan, and magenta cannot be mixed by subtracting cyan from yellow:

[image: Subtractive color mixing by Wikipedia]

<sub>Stolen from [Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_color)</sub>

---

### Creating your own primary color set

[image: color wheel]

<sub>Stolen from the [Internet](http://www.hobbitsandhobos.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/colorWheel.png)</sub>

Therefore, it is a simple matter of making up your own system of colors that fall within the specification of primary colors. Take the above color-wheel and take any equidistant positioned set of 2-3 colors<sup>1</sup>, preferably from the outer lane - and voilà, you have a set of primary colors.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Even 4+ colors could work. There will be a limit where primary colors suddenly will lose their uniqueness, as the one in the middle between two can get mixed by its negative and its positive neighbours. Depending on accuracy, this could be somewhere between 90° to 0,000001°. **To help you visualize it, just imagine a straight line between point A and point C and see how close it comes to point B.**</sub>

Furthermore, you can try [Adobe's interactive color wheel](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel?base=2&rule=Triad&selected=0&name=My%20Color%20Theme&mode=rgb&rgbvalues=0.7,0.06999999999999998,0.06999999999999998,1,0.9879032258064626,0.09999999999999998,1,0,0,0.07999999999999999,0.5221052631580096,0.8,0.03500000000000003,0.44333333333343944,0.7&swatchOrder=0,1,2,3,4) to find different combinations.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question! And I checked wikipedia before posting too!

Comment: it absolutely is. parsing hexadecimal color codes isn't really what photo.SE is about. however, I added a paragraph so it becomes more clear.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I guess you did not read my question carefully. Primary colors, based on the definition in the physics website that I provided, are defined as set of three colors that produce white when combined. C,M,Y in CMY model are not primary colors. R, Y, B are not primary colors in RYB based on this definition.

Comment: RYB would be oprimary, as you cannot get yellow out of blue and red. mind you, you could not get to white, either. besides that: do you just want to discuss? SE is for asking serious questions, not for philosophical-style "define "color" for me - and then, let us talk about your definition!"

Comment: please explain what you mean by "diametral positioned" and how you get 3 colours that way.

Comment: @ths 2 colors are diametral if they are 180° rotated. 3 colors are diametral if they each are 120° rotated. 4 colors are diametral if they are 360/4=90° rotated. I have to admit that I do not know what the limit is where the line between "primary" and "mixed" gets blurred, but I think it is around 90°. Only experimenting would tell, and I'm terribly bad in MatLab. ;-)

Comment: so, "equidistant" then.

Comment: @ths ah - you are of course right. will change that right away - thanks!

Comment: This answer isn't complete without discussion by of the cone cells in our retinas, as it's their physical behavior that makes color theory work. A spectrometer in comparison would not be fooled.

Comment: @whatsisname for a question that now is marked as off-topic (and which is generally lacking research on OP-side), this difference does not seem to be the most important thing - though you are of course right.

Comment: OP asked about mixing three single frequencies of light.  The colours in the pink/purple part of your colour wheel (anything between rainbow red and rainbow violet) don't correspond to any frequencies.  So the method of picking three points around the outside of the wheel sometimes won't work.  Also, there's no real requirement for the colours to be equidistant  - you can mix plenty of colours out of non-equidistant primaries.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem "rainbow red" and "rainbow violet" have no corresponding frequencies? Sorry for being a bit offensive here, but: WTF!? Do you even science? What do they have, then? Do they break light's [wave-particle-dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality)? Is light trinary when it appears to be purple?

Comment: I think you misread my comment. The colours _between_ red and violet (so the various pink and purple colours) can only be made by mixing other colours. There is no single frequency for any particular shade of purple. And yes, I have a science degree, thanks for asking.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem [What you mean is spectral colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_color) - I don't see how this has any effect on additive colors, unless we take into account not what is the mathematical output, but what perception allows. OP nowhere stated the goal of their "additive mix 2.0", and since the question was marked as off-topic, anyway, I really don't want to spend days to bring this answer to standards only people with degrees in physics and maths can understand. RGB was chosen because it works best with our eyes - not because it was the only feasible solution.